# PHP/SQL Checking if a value already exists in a database

Tags: php, sql

I am using the following code to check if an email address exists in a database
I am getting the email value from an HTML form.  I could verify the SQL query being executed and that part is working. 
My guess is, that I can not use the $result as I am doing it.
I always get a "not found".

```
$command = ("SELECT * FROM '$table_name'" ." WHERE email = '$email'");
$result = $db->query($command);


if (!$result )

{
echo "not found";
} 

else {
echo "found";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table name doesn't need quote.

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Then sql injection problem is another problem.